# Nested Image Field in custom Page representation wagtail api

Tags: django-rest-framework, wagtail

We are building a headless CMS with the wagtail API.
Our main model became very long, to make the representation cleaner and more easily accessible for the Frontend, 
**I am trying to group the different fields of my PageModel into sections**.

But I don't manage to serialize the nested ImageField.

This is my PageModel:

```
class LandingPage(Page):
…
introduction_headline= models.CharField()
introduction_text = RichTextField()
introduction_icon = models.ForeignKey(
    'main.CaptionImage',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name = '+',
)
…
```

I would like to group those fields into one section in the api, like so:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "meta": {…},
    "introduction_section": {
        "introduction_headline": "intro head",
        "introduction_text": "<p>intro text</p>",
        "introduction_image": {
            "id": 1,
            "meta": {
                "type": "main.CaptionImage",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/images/1/",
                "download_url": "/media/original_images/1.png"
                 },
            "title": "german_design_image.png",
            "caption": "Pretty Image"
            },
    },…
```

I managed to accomplish this in parts by writing a custom IntroductionSection - serializer:

```
class LandingPage(Page):
    …
    api_fields = [
        APIField('introduction_section', serializer=IntroductionSectionField(source='*')),
        …
    ]

class IntroductionSectionField(Field):
    read_only = True
    write_only = False

    def to_representation(self, value): 
        return {
            "introduction_headline" : value.introduction_headline,
            "introduction_text" : value.introduction_text,
            "introduction_image" : ?
    }
```

But I simply can't figure out **how to serialize the nested `Image Field`**?

I want the same representation as the standard nested-relation-representation of the page model.

I tried around with `get_related_field()` method of the `PageModel`, tried to call the `ImageSerializer`, and all sorts of other things.

Comment: Carolin did you ever figure this out?