# Defining a custom Serializer Field for related models gives TypeError

Tags: django, wagtail

My question is similar to [this unanswered question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879001/nested-image-field-in-custom-page-representation-wagtail-api)

I'm trying to implement a [serializer field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializer-fields) to my project. I'm hitting a roadblock where I need to nest other models in a single request, but it throws a `TypeError: Object of type ____ is not serializable.`

Here's what my `models.py` code's pseudocode looks like:
(`GameIndexPage` has many `GameBlogPage` has one `Game`)
(I omitted things I think is irrelevant)

```py
@register_snippet
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class GameBlogPage(Page):
    parent_page_type = ['blog.GameIndexPage']

    introduction = models.TextField

    game = models.ForeignKey 'web_api.Game'

    album_image = models.ForeignKey 'wagtailimages.Image'
    
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(form_classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()

class GameIndexPage(Page):
    subpage_types = ['GameBlogPage']

    parent_page_type = ['home.HomePage']

    introduction = RichTextField
    image = models.ForeignKey 'wagtailimages.Image'
    @property
    def children(self):
        return self.get_children().specific().public().live()
    ...
    api_fields = [
        APIField('introduction'),
        APIField('image'),
        APIField('children', serializer=GameBlogPageField())
    ]
```

Now, here's my implementation of the serializer field in `fields.py`:

```py
class GameBlogPageField(Field):

    def to_representation(self, queryset):
        pages = []
        for child in queryset:

            post_dict = {
                "id": child.id,
                "title": child.title,
                "introduction": child.introduction,
                "game": child.game # where it all goes wrong
                #"blog_authors": child.blog_authors,
                #"published_date": child.published_date,
                #"album_image": child.album_image,
            }
            pages.append(post_dict)
        return pages
```

Removing the game value gives me this result. I commented where I want the nested data to go.

```json
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "meta": {
                "type": "blog.GameIndexPage",
                ...
            },
            "title": "My Favorite Games of All Time",
            "introduction": "...",
            "image": {
                "url": "/media/original_images/_hkdd3HTVIc.jpg",
                "title": "FavGameBanner",
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1080
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "title": "...",
                    "introduction": "...",
                    "game": [] <--- I don't know of a clean way to serialize the Game object here.
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "title": "...",
                    "introduction": "...",
                    "game": [] <--- I don't know of a clean way to serialize the Game object here.
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**My dirty solution** is to manually create an object in `fields.py` and append values in them:

```py
class GameBlogPageField(Field):

    def to_representation(self, queryset):
        ...
            post_dict = {
                "id": child.id,
                "title": child.title,
                "introduction": child.introduction,
                "game": {
                    "id": child.game.id,
                    "title": child.game.title
                }
                #"blog_authors": child].blog_authors,
                #"published_date": child.published_date,
                #"album_image": child.album_image,
            }
            pages.append(post_dict)
        return pages
```

But, I can't see this working for one-to-many and many-to-many relations. Unfortunately, the only thing that I researched is the unanswered question I linked above.

What should I do?

Comment: Is writing a serializer for `GameBlogPage` not an option? You can write another nested serializer for `Game` inside it that should return the format you want

Comment: @bdbd I'm under the impression that [serializer fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializer-fields) are what Wagtail uses to serialize API responses. Is a normal serializer an option? Frankly, I'm open to other ways as this has been bugging me for days now.